# Adobe Flash and Python

Tags: python, flash, flashdevelop

Is it possible to use [CPython](http://www.python.org/) to develop Adobe Flash based applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [ming](http://www.libming.org/), a library for generating Macromedia Flash files (.swf).

It's written in C but it has wrappers that allow it to be used in C++, PHP, Python, Ruby, and Perl.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at Flex PyPy: http://code.google.com/p/flex-pypy/

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be possible to compile the python interpreter to flash bytecode using this http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/alchemy.html and then use it to run python programs. But apart from that the answer is no.