# is it possible to program ActionScript with python?

Tags: python, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

im making games in ActionScript , Flex and Flashpunk, tho i found it slow to develop in. one of my favourite programming languages are python. So i wonderd "is it possible to program ActionScript with python?". like Jython and java :P

Comment: If you want to program python instead of Actionscript, why not use that?

Comment: because flash do have a much better(and simpler) graphical platform than python and the c family.

Comment: Unless you want to create that interpreter, go ahead, but I guarantee you it won't be efficient since Python isn't view based and the paradigm changes quite abruptly.  Use the language that's better suited for you and learn it.  Ever thought that the reason why it's "slow to develop in" is your lack of skill in that particular tech?  Personally, I like strongly typed functions and what not, and an incredibly easy xml based view layout language that takes out the guess work of creating complex components. But that's just me...

Comment: i wont start on my second interpreter, so i guess i'll just program in ActionScript :P

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but maybe you can workout a nice workflow with something like pygame for python and some jsfl automation to get assets in the right format for your games from Flash, if you are using Flash. A decent IDE could speed you up. If you're on PC, FlashDevelop is better than Flex. If you want to stick to Flex get something like sourcemate. Other options are FDT and IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 1):

See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/304779/680503) where was mentioned such projects as Alchemy and PyPy. But as far as I know there is no any solution at this moment which can be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

There is an elegant way to make Actionscript 3 apps to talk to Python using Action Message Format (AMF3) and [PyAMF](http://www.pyamf.org/). The AMF3 serialized format is wicked fast (compared to XML) and can support unique data types such as ByteArray and ArrayCollection.